# Why doesn't my game loop execute

Tags: c++

I have started with C++ and I am in the middle of creating a hangman game, My code worked fine up until I chose to make three different levels of difficulty, My game asks the user for the difficulty level they would like to play, then instead of actually playing the game, it skips straight to the end where it says the user has guessed the word correctly. Any help appreciated!
The code is as follows :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void ClearScreen();
void DisplayMan0();
void DisplayMan1();
void DisplayMan2();
void DisplayMan3();
void DisplayMan4();
void DisplayMan5();
void DisplayMan6();
void DisplayMan7();


int main()
{

    const int MAX_WRONG = 7;  // incorrect guesses allowed
    void (*pfnaDisplayMan[])() = {DisplayMan0, DisplayMan1, DisplayMan2, DisplayMan3, DisplayMan4, DisplayMan5, DisplayMan6, DisplayMan7};

    vector<string> words;  // Level 1 
    words.push_back("GREEN");
    words.push_back("BANANA");
    words.push_back("LAPTOP");
    words.push_back("GIRAFFE");
    words.push_back("PENCIL");

    vector<string> wordsD1;  // Level 2
    wordsD1.push_back("DELICIOUS");
    wordsD1.push_back("COMPUTING");
    wordsD1.push_back("SOFTWARE");
    wordsD1.push_back("HARDWARE");
    wordsD1.push_back("TELEPHONE");

    vector<string> wordsD2; // Level 3
    wordsD2.push_back("BAMBOOZLED");
    wordsD2.push_back("DAYDREAMER");
    wordsD2.push_back("CANNIBALISM");
    wordsD2.push_back("NERVOUSLY");
    wordsD2.push_back("APPROACHING");


    srand((unsigned int)time(0));


    string THE_WORD;
    string soFar;
    int wordLength;
    string used;                         // letters already guessed


      cout << "\t\t HANGMAN\n";

    cout << "Please enter a difficulty level [1-3] ";
    int dif = 0;
    while(dif < 1 || dif > 3)
    {
        cin >> dif;
    }
    cout << "You have chosen difficulty level : "<< dif << endl;


    if(dif == 1)
    {
        random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end());
        int incorrectGuesses = 0;                            // number of incorrect guesses
        string const THE_WORD = words[0];         // word to guess
        string soFar(THE_WORD.size(), '*');       // word guessed so far
        // count length of randomly chosen string and display it 
        wordLength = THE_WORD.length();
    }
    if(dif == 2)
    {
        random_shuffle(wordsD1.begin(), wordsD1.end());
        int incorrectGuesses = 0;                            // number of incorrect guesses
        string const THE_WORD = wordsD1[0];        
        string soFar(THE_WORD.size(), '*');  
        wordLength = THE_WORD.length();
    }
    if(dif == 3)
    {
        random_shuffle(wordsD2.begin(), wordsD2.end());
        int incorrectGuesses = 0;                            // number of incorrect guesses
        string const THE_WORD = wordsD2[0];        
        string soFar(THE_WORD.size(), '*');       
        wordLength = THE_WORD.length();
    }




    // main loop
    while ((incorrectGuesses < MAX_WRONG) && (soFar != THE_WORD))
    {
         cout << "\n- There are : "<< wordLength <<" letters in the word :\t" << soFar << endl;
        cout << "\n- You have guessed  " <<incorrectGuesses << " times wrong out of "<< MAX_WRONG  << " allowed wrong guesses.\n";
        cout << "\nLetters used : " << used << endl;

        cout << "=====================================================";

        char guess;
        cout << "\n\t\tEnter a letter :  ";
        cin >> guess;

        guess = toupper(guess); //make uppercase since secret word in uppercase

        while (used.find(guess) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "\nYou've already guessed the letter " << guess << endl;
            cout << "Enter another letter / word: ";
            cin >> guess;

            guess = toupper(guess);
        }

        used += guess;

        if (THE_WORD.find(guess) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "=====================================================\n";
            cout << "- Correct, The letter " << guess << " is in the word.\n";


            // update soFar to include newly guessed letter
            for (int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i)
                if (THE_WORD[i] == guess)
                    soFar[i] = guess;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry, " << guess << " isn't in the word.\n";
            ++incorrectGuesses;
            pfnaDisplayMan[incorrectGuesses]();

        }
    }

    // shut down
    if (incorrectGuesses == MAX_WRONG)
        cout << "\nYou've been hanged!";
    else
        cout << "\nYou guessed it!";

    cout << "\nThe word was " << THE_WORD << endl;

    return 0;
}

    void DisplayMan0() 
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "________" << endl;
}

void DisplayMan1()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "________" << endl;
}

void DisplayMan2() 
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "________" << endl;
}

void DisplayMan3() 
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /X" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "________" << endl;
}

void DisplayMan4() 
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /X\\" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "________" << endl;
}

void DisplayMan5() 
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /X\\" << endl;
    cout << "|    /" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "________" << endl;
}

void DisplayMan6() 
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /X\\" << endl;
    cout << "|    / \\" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "________" << endl;
}
void DisplayMan7() 
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "\t\t_______" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|DONT"   << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|HANG"   << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|THE"    << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|MAN"    << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|             O" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t| _______    /XL" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t__|_____|   / \\" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `test.cpp:99:13: error: ‘incorrectGuesses’ was not declared in this scope
     while ((incorrectGuesses < MAX_WRONG) && (soFar != THE_WORD))
             ^
test.cpp:145:9: error: ‘incorrectGuesses’ was not declared in this scope
     if (incorrectGuesses == MAX_WRONG)
`

Comment: Ok, get rid of all of the `using namespace std;` in the functions. You're going to type that more than you would `std::`. If you *must* have it (I recommend against), put one up at the top.

Comment: Also, have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: @crashmstr Ironically enough... he has it at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `incorrectGuesses` out of those scopes. Because out of those scopes this variable is not declared.

```
if(dif == 1)
{
    int incorrectGuesses = 0; 
    ...
}
if(dif == 2)
{
    int incorrectGuesses = 0; 
    ...
}
if(dif == 3)
{
    int incorrectGuesses = 0;
    ...
}
```

Should be

```
int incorrectGuesses = 0; 

if(dif == 1)
{
    ...
}
if(dif == 2)
{
    ...
}
if(dif == 3)
{
    ...
}
```

Same issues for `soFar`, `THE_WORD` and `wordLength`. That part of code should be like this:

```
string THE_WORD;
string soFar;
int wordLength;
string used;

// cout ... cin ....


int incorrectGuesses = 0;


if(dif == 1)
{
    random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end());

    THE_WORD = words[0];         // word to guess
    wordLength = THE_WORD.length();
}
if(dif == 2)
{
    random_shuffle(wordsD1.begin(), wordsD1.end());
    THE_WORD = wordsD1[0];
    wordLength = THE_WORD.length();
}
if(dif == 3)
{
    random_shuffle(wordsD2.begin(), wordsD2.end());
    THE_WORD = wordsD2[0];
    wordLength = THE_WORD.length();
}

soFar.assign(THE_WORD.size(), '*');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! When I made these changes it still does the same thing - skip the actual game loop itself! Can you suggest any other changes? Thanks

Comment: @Ronan: You have same issue for another variables, [THIS](http://ideone.com/ULhigq) is a working code. Copy/Paste and enjoy it.

Comment: @Ronan If you plan to be a programmer, recommend you take this problem and strip it down to the minimal code that reproduces the problem so that you understand where you went wrong. Also, as you said it "skip[s] the actual game loop" that means one of these two conditions was failing `(incorrectGuesses < MAX_WRONG) && (soFar != THE_WORD)`. Set a break point on that line and run the broken version in your debugger (if using visual studio, get used to starting your program by hitting f11 to debug from the start of main), and inspect "incorrectGuesses", "soFar" and "THE_WORD".

Comment: Developing those techniques early will make it much less painful next time you run into an issue :)

Answer (score 1):

M M. is correct. Your redeclaring the variables.
Just a small remark. I would use a Switch Case instead of a set of if statements. Changing:

```
if(dif==1){}
if(dif==2){}
if(dif==3){}
```

into

```
switch(dif){
   case(1):
      break;
   case(2):
      break;
   case(3):
      break;
}
```

Not for necessarily for readability but more to indicate that the value of dif isn't edited depending upon its value. For example:
Option 1:

```
dif = 1;
if(dif==1){ dif = 3; }
if(dif==2){}
if(dif==3){ dif = 7; }
```

Versus:
Option 2

```
dif = 1;
switch(dif){
   case(1):
      dif = 3;
      break;
   case(2):
      break;
   case(3):
      dif = 7;
      break;
}
```

Option 1 output: 7 
Option 2 output: 3

Answer (score 0):

You declare `incorrectGuesses` out of scope. It is NEVER declared or assigned a value. Declare it at the beginning of your function and assign it value in the other scopes.